# Django. Как получить значение внешнего ключа?

Tags: python, django

Проблема в том, что мне нужно отфильтровать книги по жанру , а  поле жанра является внешним ключом, поэтому  выдается ошибка. Как получить значение? Я же не буду каждый id вручную смотреть

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Книги')
    genre=models.ForeignKey('Genre', null=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Жанр')
```

А вот с другого файла вызываю и происходит ошибка

```
detectives = Books.objects.filter(genre='Детектив')
```

> ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Детектив'.

Comment: Можно смотреть не вручную

Comment: Обычно такие вещи отображаются на странице в выпадающего списка `<select>`, а значения элементов этого списка содержат эти самые id, которые сюда тривиально запихиваются. То, что вы по какой-то причине решили запихнуть строку, странно само по себе — вы уверены, что вам действительно это надо?

Comment: нужно отфильтровать по жанру книги, и передать в шаблон детективы

Comment: Обычно пользователь сам выбирает нужный жанр из выпадающего списка, который содержит в себе все нужные id. Как у вас так получилось, что вы почему-то стали запихивать строку?

Comment: Я создаю  inclusion tag @register.inclusion_tag('menu.html')
def draw_menu(menu_title):
    if menu_title=='main_menu':
        genres = Genre.objects.all()[:5]
        detectives = Books.objects.filter(genre='Детектив')
        return {"genres":genres,'detectives':detectives}

Comment: У вас детектив является особенным жанром, который выделяется среди других? Странноватая логика

Comment: Ну и как мне на это реагировать? За своей следите! Помогли бы лучше чем писать неприятные вещи

Comment: Чтобы вам помочь, нужно сперва понять, чего вы хотите, а сейчас выглядит так, будто вы хотите [забивать гвозди микроскопом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709). Я не люблю помогать забивать гвозди микроскопом, поэтому хочу понять, что вам нужно на самом деле

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144343/discussion-between---and-andreymal).

Comment: Тем не менее, в данном конкретно примере вероятно прокатит просто `.filter(genre__name='Детектив')`, но учитывая вашу странноватую логику, я не уверен, что это как-то поможет вам в дальнейшем

Comment: (ах да, на месте `name` должно быть имя того поля, которое хранит в себе название жанра, но так вы не показали модель Genre, я не в курсе, какое поле есть у вас)

Comment: Вы сейчас на что отвечаете? На сообщение в чате , что я оставил?

Comment: Код модели в этом вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1501873/django-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c?noredirect=1#comment2693432_1501873